android get time in given timezone ignoring device's current time
I should get the time in my country not depending on in which timezone user is in or which time he set manually from the settings of device.
Below code works when user sets different timezone, it converts the timestamp correctly
But when user sets a manual time without changing the timezone, then because timeInMillis will be in Asia/Baku timezone it just returns the same date, which isn't a case I want.
fun convertTimeStampToAzerbaijanTimeStamp(timeInMillis: Long): Long? {
    return try {
        val date = Date(timeInMillis)
        val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_GENERAL, Locale.getDefault()).apply {
            timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZONE_ID_BAKU)
        }
        val formattedDate = dateFormatter.format(date)
        (dateFormatter.parse(formattedDate) as Date).time
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
}


Use an SNTP client to get the current time from a time server.

The java.util date-time API is outdated and error-prone. You should use java.time API.

You can get the current time from about any server. You may want to make sure that you know which server you are getting the time from so you don’t get it from a server on which the time has been set incorrectly.
